# Unable to install Phonegap: gyp ERR! configure error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.makeatrail.com/how-to-run-your-phonegap-android-app-on-a-windows-pc-and-test-it-on-your-connected-android-device-or-emulator/) in installing phonegap. My computer is Windows 7 64 bit.

However when I run `npm install -g phonegap` in step 4 of the above tutorial, I am getting errors. The errors displayed in CMD are below

```
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\nod
e_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_mo
dules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

/
C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-ph
onegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if not defi
ned npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bi
n\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (no
de  rebuild )

> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\nod
e_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\
node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

|
C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-ph
onegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.
io-client\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program F
iles (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp
\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

The `builderror.log` file contains the below information.

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

How can I fix this issue and install phonegap properly?

Comment: the blog entry is a bit dated.. Yeah Cordova/Phonegap is now shipping Android SDK 23 and iOS9, as of a few weeks ago. Try this blog, and see if it can help you [iPhoneDevlog](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/workflow/). The author frequents [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) so more help is available

Comment: Why not trying to install python or setting env-variable PYTHON if python has already been installed as your error-log indicates?

Answer (score 0):

If possible Try reinstalling node.js with current stable version.

and then in your command prompt

npm install -g phonegap@latest

GoodLuck

Comment: Every thing are newly installed. anything with python?

Comment: Yes for Node --> Current version: v4.2.3

Note: Python 2.6 or 2.7 is required to build from source tarballs.          refer: https://nodejs.org/en/download/